# What are the cutting edge technologies for a complete makeover?

Tags: society

The recruits are young women. They undergo surgery, genetic alterations, and conditioning. **What are the plausible technologies to do that?**

The checks in the world are basically fitness and cognitive tests. Of course upper class citizens behave very differently from lower class ones. So the ultimate test is fitting in.

Comment: Dystopian science-fiction adventure novels set on Mars hundreds of years in the future *"are not very realistic"*? Totally unexpected. And the science *"might not be plausible"* . . . because it is hundreds of years in the future. Think what readers in the 1300s would have thought about Tracy Kidder's thoroughly non-fiction [*Soul of a New Machine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Soul_of_a_New_Machine). (And "plausible" refers to the audience accepting the story; it does not mean "realistic". Goddess Aphrodite physically fighting the Achaeans is plausible in the context of the *Iliad*.)

Comment: Given that identity thieves routinely steal identities of people who look nothing like them, I would propose that the technology needed is that to obtain the identity info of target persons.  Also cosmetic surgery for pectoral implants like Ricardo Montalban in Wrath of Khan.

Comment: For those of us who haven't read or even heard of the "red rising" books, what are the challenges that need to be overcome?  For example, you say "genetic alterations" - do the imposters need to be able to pass DNA tests?  Very different requirements to impersonate a recluse vs a socialiser working in a futuristic secure building who has to pass fingerprint, retina scan and/or DNA tests every day plus carry on conversations with people who have known them well for many years.

Comment: (a) Please be aware that we do not answer questions about 3rd party or commercial worlds. Although you're asking about real-world technologies, you're doing it on behalf of someone else's world. In a nutshell, we only answer questions about your world. As a new user, we're lenient, but please keep this in mind, it'll get Qs like this closed in the future. (b) There's a considerable difference between "believable" and "realistic." Why does it matter that the technologies be "realistic?" compared to today's technologies?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we don't respond to questions about someone else's fictional world. We're here to help you with questions about your own work!

Comment: Vote to close!!!

Comment: Do not vandalize any posts, even your own.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

1. Rebuilding of the organism at the cellular and anatomical level  with the help of viroids and nanomachines, nanobots, nanotechnologies.
2. Neuroconstructions and neuromodification - for changes in consciousness;
   chemical, surgical and using the same nanomachines.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanorobotics